# How can I generalize getting values from a dictionary key?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, formatting

I have a list of dictionaries such as:

> [ {'Type': 'Water', 'Level': '8'}, {'Type': 'Fire', 'Level': '2'}, {'Type': 'Fire', 'Level': '8'}, ... ]

I have this code that basically prints it as a table:

```
my_list_of_dics = [ {'Type': 'Water', 'Level': '8'}, {'Type': 'Fire', 'Level': '2'}, {'Type': 'Fire', 'Level': '8'}]

#Initialize string
string_table = ""

#Print headers
for key in my_list_of_dics[0]:
    string_table += key + "\t"

#Jump line
string_table += "\n"

#Print values (rows), matching the header order and tabulations between each value and jump a line after each row
for row in my_list_of_dics:
    string_table += row['Type'] + "\t" + row['Level'] + "\n"

print(string_table)
```

Prints this:

> ```
> Type  Level   
> Water 8
> Fire  2
> Fire  8
> ```

It works as I want it, however I have to hardcode the names of the keys and the number of tabulations (+"\t") between each when printing it out.

Generating the headers of the table is fortunately generalized, however I haven't beeen able to generalize the printing key's values and the number of tabulations (as seen in my 2nd loop).

Comment: Do all the dictionaries have the same keys?

Comment: Yes, all dictionaries would have the same keys. It's basically a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the dictionaries have the same keys, you can replace the line of code in your `for` loop with:

```py
string_table += '\t'.join(row[key] for key in my_list_of_dics[0]) + '\n'
```

Note you can optimise this by defining

```
keys = list(my_list_of_dics[0].keys())
```

then you can just use

```
string_table += '\t'.join(row[key] for key in keys) + '\n'
```

and you can make the first line of the table with

```
string_table = '\t'.join(keys) + '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python `format` to create tables.

```
my_list_of_dics = [
    {"Type": "Water", "Level": "8"},
    {"Type": "Fire", "Level": "2"},
    {"Type": "Fire", "Level": "8"},
]

print("{:<10} {:<10}".format("Type", "Level"))
for val in my_list_of_dics:
    print("{:<10} {:<10}".format(val["Type"], val["Level"]))
```

will give us

```
Type       Level     
Water      8         
Fire       2         
Fire       8
```

More generalized form

```
my_list_of_dics = [
    {"Type": "Water", "Level": "8"},
    {"Type": "Fire", "Level": "2"},
    {"Type": "Fire", "Level": "8"},
]

get_keys = list(my_list_of_dics[0].keys())
fmt = "{:<10}" * len(get_keys)
print(fmt.format(*get_keys))
for val in my_list_of_dics:
    print(fmt.format(*val.values()))
```